# having an issue with displaying more than one line with BufferedReader

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I'm trying to display more than one line, but instead of getting any input, all I get is a "null".

```
public void display ()
{
    BufferedReader display;
    try
    {
        display = new BufferedReader (new FileReader (fileName));
        while (line != null)
        {
            line = display.readLine ();
        }
        display.close ();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
    }

    c.println (fileName + " display: ");
    c.println (line);
}
```

Comment: There is missing code here, what is c ? Where is line assigned ? And what do you mean by all I gest is a null ? get from where ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/DR3FFT6R
Here is the full code on pastebin.

Comment: @GilLitvak, please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can focus on the core problem.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call `line = display.readLine();`, it throws away the old value of `line`

To get the whole contents of the file, you must save them or print them out as you read.

To save them, try setting a contents variable like this

```
public void display()
{
    BufferedReader display;
    String contents = "";
    try
    {
        display = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        while(line != null)
        {
            line = display.readLine();
            contents += line + "\n";
        }
        display.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e){}

    c.println(fileName + " display: ");
    c.println(contents);
}
```

The above code will get you the contents of each line, including the null.  You can use an if statement to remove the null value at the end, or change up the while loop a bit

I find it's a bit easier to condense the while loop and do stuff with each line

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
String contents = "";
String line;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    contents += line + "\n"; //or doStuff(line); if you process data line by line
System.out.println(contents);
```

What may make even more sense than a while loop is to use a for loop

```
for(String line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine())
    contents += line + "\n";
```

Comment: @ankhzet Not a bad idea, added it in.  Usually I just pass it to another function or build a LinkedList with the data

Comment: same for me. Also, i wonder how `while(line != null) { line = display.readLine();...` will even works... Erm, loop will never starts if `line == null` at the start of the method call, right? Such a mistery...

Comment: @ankhzet My best guess is that line is defined beforehand to be the empty string.  Just checked his pastebin and it is defined at the top (which is rather odd for a temp variable) as ""

Comment: Btw, `for`-version doesn't looks nice, imho. `while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)` used much frequent, afaik.

Comment: @ankhzet I too use the compacted while loop more often, but it does follow pretty much the exact format a for loop is for so I added it in